Smallest dimension, on which a set of matrices acts non-trivially
Let $A_i$, $i=1,\dots,N$, be a finite set of $D<\infty$ dimensional Hermitian matrices. Let $d$ be the smallest number for which there exists a unitary $D$-dimensional matrix $U$, and Hermitian $d$-dimensional matrix $a_i$, such that
$$
U A_i U^\dagger = a_i\otimes 1_{D/d}\,,
$$
where $1_{D/d}$ is $(D/d)$-dimensional identity.
Is there a name for number $d$, and is there a way of constructing matrix $U$?

I'm not sure I fully understand the question so this is more of a query than anything - the eigenvalues of $a_i \otimes I_{D/d}$ are just the eigenvalues of $a_i$ repeated $D/d$ times so it seems that if the eigenvalues of any of the $A_i$ are distinct then $d = D$. On the other hand to make $d$ any smaller than that you need the eigenvalues of $A_i$ to share multiplicities somehow?

Yes, to have a non-trivial answer, all eigenvalues of all $A_i$ must have a multiplicity of a multiple of some $d'$ that divides $D$. This however does not guarantee that $d = D/d'$.

Every algebra of matrices can be written as a direct sum of tensors like you've written, and you're basically asking whether or not the algebra generating by the $A_i$s has just one term (i.e., no direct sum). Vrej Zarikian wrote a preprint that solves this problem (and a couple others) called "Algorithms for Operator Algebra Calculations" in 2003. However, I am not able to find a public copy of this paper anywhere online, so I am hesitant to share it without permission. Maybe you could e-mail him and ask? usna.edu/Users/math/zarikian/index.php

is the Zarikian paper the same as https://www.usna.edu/Users/math/zarikian/_files/documents/ap.pdf

@CarloBeenakker - Not the same. The preprint I have includes the alternating-projection stuff from that paper, but also contains a bunch of other stuff (i.e., the stuff relevant to the OP here) that I'm not sure was ever published anywhere. Here's a screenshot of the title and abstract.
